# Convert delegate to Action<T> (Action<T1,T2>)

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

I have a DB class that makes all DB calls like below:

```
public delegate void Part1_Callback(string message);
public delegate void Part2_Callback(DataTable dt);
public delegate void Part3_Callback(DataTable dt, int x, int y);
public delegate void ErrorHandler(string message);

public class CommandAndCallback<TCallback>
{
    public SqlCommand Sql { get; set; }
    public TCallback Callback { get; set; }
    public ErrorHandler Error { get; set; }
}

class DB : SingletonBase<DB>
{
    public static readonly string SqlConnectionString  = @"Data Source=MyDB;Initial Catalog=Stats;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=true;";

    private DB()
    {
    }

    public void Part2(Part2_Callback callback, ErrorHandler error)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Part2";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error(ex.ToString());
            return;
        }

        CommandAndCallback<Part2_Callback> ar = new CommandAndCallback<Part2_Callback>() { Callback = callback, Error = error, Sql = cmd };
        IAsyncResult result = cmd.BeginExecuteReader(new AsyncCallback(Part2_Handler), ar, CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }

    private void Part2_Handler(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        CommandAndCallback<Part2_Callback> ar = (CommandAndCallback<Part2_Callback>)result.AsyncState;
        SqlDataReader dr;

        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            dr = ar.Sql.EndExecuteReader(result);
        }
        else
            dr = null;

        dt.Load(dr);
        dr.Close();
        dt.Columns[3].ReadOnly = false;
        ar.Callback(dt);
    }
}
```

And in my main class I'm using it like so:

```
    private void Form1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showStatus("Loading");
        DB.Instance.Part2(Part2_OK, ErrorHandler);
    }
    private void ErrorHandler(string msg)
    {
        hideStatus();
        viewStack1.InvokeIfRequired(c => { c.moveToFirst(); });
        //MessageBox.Show(msg, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    private void Part2_OK(DataTable dt)
    {
        dataGridView1.InvokeIfRequired(c =>
        {
            c.DataSource = dt;
        });
    }
```

Right now I have 3 methods in my DB class that return 3 different sets of data, for every type I must declare delegate.
If in future I'll add more methods then I'll have to add more delegates.

Can I remove usage of delegates? I would like to simplify build of my class so that it will be easy to add new methods.

What I need is to be able to call my DB Class like so:

```
DB.Instance.PartX(PartX_OK, ErrorHandler);
```

PartX is declared as shown

```
private void PartX_OK(DataTable dt, int x, int y, ...)
{
//logic here
}
```

Can `Action<T>` be used to to that, so I can call my handlers with multiple parameters? If yes then how?

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to use the same method handler as the value for the `Part2_Callback` **and** the `Part3_Callback`?

Comment: In main class I have different handlers for every method in my DB class. But right now I must define delegates for every method (if it takes different types of arguments or different number of them), I would like to get rid of that. So that I can have one generic delegate or 2 delegates (one for one parameter, second for two parameters). As I mentioned I would like to try using `Action<T>` but I don't know how

Comment: Okay. It looks to me like @JustinHarvey has what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I meant to get back to your earlier question, so your function would become

```
public void Part2(Action<DataTable> callback, ErrorHandler error)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Part2";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error(ex.ToString());
        return;
    }

    CommandAndCallback<Action<DataTable>> ar = new CommandAndCallback<Action<DataTable>>() { Callback = callback, Error = error, Sql = cmd };
    IAsyncResult result = cmd.BeginExecuteReader(new AsyncCallback(Part2_Handler), ar, CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}

        private void Part2_Handler(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        CommandAndCallback<Action<DataTable>> ar = (CommandAndCallback<Action<DataTable>>)result.AsyncState;
        SqlDataReader dr;

        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            dr = ar.Sql.EndExecuteReader(result);
        }
        else
            dr = null;

        dt.Load(dr);
        dr.Close();
        dt.Columns[3].ReadOnly = false;
        ar.Callback(dt);
    }
```

Comment: and then in my main class I call my method like so: `DB.Instance.Part2(Part2_OK, ErrorHandler)` So I must have two `CommandAndCallback` classes? One for Action with 1 parameter and one for 2 parameters?

Comment: No, the `CommandAndCallback` class is generic and is only storing the callbacks, so there should be no need for more than one of those.

Answer (score 2):

There are `Action` classes with upto 16 generic parameters, you will probably find the one for your needs;). See [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx).

And the invocation

```
DB.Instance.PartX((p1, p2, p3, p4) => { ... }, ErrorHandler);
```

Comment: It's a shame that I can only select one answer, because every one was helpful, but I've selected @Justin's answer because of the code sample.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Part1_Callback` will be equivilant to `Action<string>`
2. `Part2_Callback` will be equivilant to `Action<DataTable>`
3. `Part3_Callback` will be equivilant to `Action<DataTable, int, int>`
4. `ErrorHandler` will be equivilant to `Action<string>`

Just use those types in place of each of your existing delegates.

There are almost no cases anymore where you need to define your own delegates.  If you have >16 parameters, `ref/out` parameters, `params` parameters, or optional arguments then there may not be an Action/Func overload for you, but that's not particularly common.

Comment: But how should I define my `CommandAndCallback` class? It is passed as a parameter in BeginExecuteReader?

Comment: @Misiu What about it?  You can pretty much just do a find/replace with the `Action` types to replace your custom types.  When you do that do you have any problems or errors?

Comment: So I don't need to change `CommandAndCallback`? I was trying to change it to something weird, but when I leave it as it was my application started working :) I'll test rest of my methods with multiple parameters and write back if I get any errors. Thanks for clearing that :)

Comment: It's a shame that I can only select one answer, because every one was helpful, but I've selected @Justin's answer because of the code sample.